# How do I avoid applying a class to a span inside a Div?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible or the best practice to avoid putting a class on a `span` which is nested inside a `div`?

I have the stereotypical 'to-do list' learning project and I need to line-through the item when clicked on but I also have a span element in there which will later be a delete button to remove the entire `li`.

`<li><span class="deleteBtn">X</span> Birthday Cake</li>`

At the moment the line-through is obviously targeting the span as well, so I'm wondering if there's a simple way to avoid it without a hack, otherwise I'm guessing I probably need to make the text a separate `span` and apply the line-through class to those `span`'s

Comment: use selector such as `div > span`

Comment: Thanks guys but I'm trying NOT to target the `span` and only the text inside the `li` which is 'Birthday Cake' in the example I gave. So just to be clear, I want 'Birthday Cake' to have a line through but not the `<span>X </span>`

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible or the best practice to avoid putting a class on a span which is nested inside a div?

Yes it is possible.

```
li > span{
  /* styles */
}
```

Is it best practice? Not necessarily. I've found its helpful to have sub classes within divs or spans. Gives you greater control, even if you're not using them, for future development it might make your life easier.

Check out CSS selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp), should give you a better understanding of what you can achieve. Regarding my example above, the first child of a `li` element has to be a span for that styling to take effect. Doing the following will apply to any span within an `li` element regardless of nested amount.

```
li span {
    /* styles */
}
```

EDIT:
After seeing your comment, I think what I put still stands, however you should wrap your inner text in an element, another `span` should do it.

```
<li>
  <span class="deleteBtn">X</span>
  <span class="ItemText">Birthday Cake</span>
</li>
```

This will give you the ability to add your CSS in the following way.

```
li > .ItemText{
  <!-- styles -->
}
```

It may seem over the top, but like I mentioned before it will give you greater control, I wouldn't consider it bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution ! you can use < div >< /div> or < p >< /p > tag like the following:

```
<li><span class="deleteBtn">X</span><p class="to-do-list"> Birthday Cake</p></li>
```

and then insteed of applying your CSS to all < li > , you just need to apply it to your .to-do-list class

Hope this help ! Feel free to let me know is you have any questions !